# Erlang SIP Client library

Tags: erlang, sip

I want to program an application written by Erlang, the features are that SIP/TLS userA makes call to SIP/TLS userB, B answers the call, B holds and resume the call. In order to do that I need Erlang SIP client libraries I think. Is it correct? If yes, can someone let me know what is the name of those libraries?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Google finds  https://github.com/fredrikt/yxa and https://github.com/kalta/nksip. We have used the latter without any serious problems.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry Belyaev! As I know yxa works as SIP proxy. I need SIP Client library, it seems that nksip is a thing I am looking for. Thanks again.